# X1 X2 independent variables exponential distribution - Looking for simpler solution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-function

> Let $X_1  \sim \exp(\lambda)$ and $X_2 \sim \exp(\lambda)$ be two independent exponentially distributed random variables. Find the mean and variance of random variable $Y=X_1 + X_2$.

$x=x_1 + x_2 $

$$f_x(X)= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_{x_1}(x_1) - f_{x_2}(x-x_1)dx = \dots$$

$$ \dfrac{λ^2}{Γ(2)} x^{2-1}e^{-λx} , x>0$$

$E(x)=\dfrac{2}{λ}$  $V(x)=\dfrac{2}{λ^2}$

I am trying to find if this can be solved easier...

Comment: What is $\lambda$?

Comment: number λ>0.. numba :)

Comment: @Parhs I think that what Henry is trying to get at is that your problem has $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ but no $\lambda$. Your solution has $\lambda$, but no $\lambda_1$ or $\lambda_2$. There is no connection between your problem and your solution, which is very confusing. You have not expressed yourself very clearly.

Comment: i am sorry i did copy paste for the first sentence :( editing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are **any** random variables, and $a$ and $b$ are constants, then
$$E(aX+bY)=aE(X)+bE(Y).$$

If $X$ and $Y$ are **independent** random variables, and $a$ and $b$ are constants, then
$$\text{Var}(aX+bY)=a^2\text{Var}(X)+b^2\text{Var}(Y).$$

In our case we have $a=b=1$, but the general expressions may be useful to you later.

So you don't need to find the distribution of the random variable $X_1+X_2$, all you need is formulas for the mean and variance of an exponential random variable $T$ with parameter $\lambda$. These are respectively $\dfrac{1}{\lambda}$ and $\dfrac{1}{\lambda^2}$. Thus your mean and variance are respectively
$$\frac{1}{\lambda_1}+\frac{1}{\lambda_2}\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{1}{\lambda_1^2}+\frac{1}{\lambda_2^2}.$$

**Edit:** The question was changed. It turns out that $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda$. that is just a special case of the above formulas.

It is not clear whether you were asking also about how to compute the *individual* means and variances, or whether you already know these.
We need $E(T)$, and $E(T^2)$, since $\text{Var}(T)=E(T^2)-(E(T))^2$.

The expectations can be found as usual by integration. There are some shortcuts, but they tend to involve more advanced notions. In case you are interested, let me mention the term *moment generating function*.

**Added:** We compute the moment generating function $m(s)$ of our random variable $T$ (sorry about $s$, the traditional $t$ is already taken). So we want 
$$E(e^{Ts})=\int_0^\infty e^{ts}\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\,dt=\int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-(\lambda-s)t}\,dt.$$ 
Integrate by substitution, easy. We get 
$$m(s)=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-s}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{s}{\lambda}}.$$
So $m(s)$ has a very nice Taylor expansion $m(s)=1+\frac{1}{\lambda}s+\frac{1}{\lambda^2}s^2+\cdots$. From this we can pick up $E(X^k)$ for any $k$. In particular, $E(X)=\frac{1}{\lambda}$, and $E(X^2)=\frac{2!}{\lambda^2}$.

We can even get the moment-generating function of $X_1+X_2$, since the mgf of an independent sum is the product of the mgf's..

Comment: thanks a lot , i have computed the moment generating function  before this, but how can it help here ?Also sorry i mistyped there is only $λ_1$ not $λ_1$ $λ_2$

Comment: i meant only $λ$

Answer (score 0):

you can solve the problem from poisson point process.
imagine a lot of points arriving one after another.
If the time $x_i$ between each   arrival point is stable exponential distribution with intensity $\lambda$, the total number of arrival  photons in a time period obeys poisson distribution.
While the  time of nth arrival point $S_n(x_1+x_2+...x_n)$ obeys Gamma distribution. your question is asking the distribution function of 2th arrival time($x_1+x_2$), you can just substitute the 2 into the Gamma function.

if $S_n$ is the arrival time of nth point in poisson process, its density function is
$g_n(s)=\lambda ^{n} s^{n-1}e^{-\lambda s}/ \varGamma(n)$ .
so $g_n(2)=\lambda ^{2} se^{-\lambda s}/ \varGamma(2)$ is your answer.
you can find this function in any stochastic process book.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).